# iptables inserts duplicate rules when name localhost is used instead of 127.0.0.1

Tags: linux-kernel, iptables

When I insert a rule into the INPUT chain, it's duplicated twice (that is, along with the original rule, there are three exact copies). Here's the command given: `/sbin/iptables -w -I INPUT 20 -m comment -p tcp -s localhost -d localhost --comment 'TEST' -j LOG`

This behavior manifests on a CentOS machine (`Linux version 3.10.0-1127.8.2.el7.x86_64`), an Ubuntu machine (Linux version 5.6.1-x86), and a pristine Debian box (`Linux version 4.19.0-9-amd64`).

However, when I replace `localhost` with `127.0.0.1`, this does not occur (if I replace just one  `localhost` value with its corresponding address, only one duplicate is made). Note that, when I attempt to pass the `-n` argument to `iptables`, it tells me, ironically enough, that this option cannot be used with insert (`Illegal option '-n' with this command`). However, if I run `strace` to see what it's up to, it's clear that `iptables` is opening `/etc/resolv.conf` (but only when I use `localhost` as a value, not its IP address).

Is this by design?

**Update:** Here is what is contained in `/etc/hosts` for localhost and `127.0.0.1`:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost                                 
127.0.1.1       ubuntu.nodes.hosting.com       ubuntu    
...                                                          
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
```

**Update 2:** Thanks to @9000's comments, I looked at the hosts file. Given an `/etc/hosts` file that contains the following lines (and no other references to `localhost`)...

```
127.0.0.1   localhost 
::1         localhost
```

...commenting out the second line (that is, the line that associates the name `localhost` with the IPv6 address `::1`), this command...

```
/sbin/iptables -w -I INPUT 20 -m comment -p tcp -s localhost -d localhost --comment 'TEST' -j LOG
```

...only generates a single rule.

Why would an IPv6 address be parsed or have any effect on behavior, given that I'm invoking `/sbin/iptables` and not `/sbin/ip6tables`? Both are linked to `xtables-multi`. It seems as if there's no check to see which version is intended by the user. Moreover, the duplicate rules that are inserted don't vary by IP version; all of them use an IPv4 address to indicated both source and destination.

Comment: Just in case, how many entries for `localhost` are there in `/etc/hosts`? E.g. there can be mappings to `127.0.0.1` and to `::1`.

Comment: @9000 You seem to be onto something. There are two entries for `127.0.0.1`. I'll update the question with the contents of the file.

Comment: Look how the `uduntu` entry is `127.0.1.1`, which is also the local network, but a different IP address. Each machine has its own 127/24 IPv4 network, and routing rules for different addresses in it can potentially make sense. E.g. you could have a number of servers running on the same host and listening on the same port, but on different 127.x.x.x addresses. You'd might want to firewall off some of them, but not others.

Comment: @9000 Thanks for the comments. I've updated the question to reflect them.